# Install Manjaro alongside Windows and Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: boot, partitioning, grub2, uefi

I tried to install Manjaro Gnome on a system with a Windows partition and an Ubuntu 20.04 partition.

I do this -

```
EFI PARTITION
Select the unpartitioned space → Create
a. Size → input 512
b. Filesystem → select FAT32
c. Mountpoint → select /boot/efi
d. Flags → check boot → OK
SWAP PARTITION
Select the unpartitioned space → Create
a. Size → input 2048
b. Filesystem → select linuxswap → OK
ROOT PARTITION
Select the unpartitioned space → Create
a. Size → input 20480 (min. recommended size)
b. Filesystem → select ext4
c. Mountpoint → select / (root) → OK
```

Now, at system startup, grub does not feature Ubuntu 20.04.

I got, after running the commands -

[ -d /sys/firmware/efi ] && echo UEFI || echo BIOS

```
UEFI
```

sudo os-prober

```
/dev/sda12:Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (20.04):Ubuntu:linux
/dev/sda2@/efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi:Windows Boot Manager:Windows:efi
```

sudo parted -l

```
Model: ATA TOSHIBA MQ01ABD1 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 1000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system     Name                  Sinalizador
 1      1049kB  1075MB  1074MB  ntfs            Basic data partition  escondida, diag
 2      1075MB  1180MB  105MB   fat32           Basic data partition  boot, esp
 3      1180MB  1314MB  134MB   ntfs            Basic data partition  msftres
 4      1314MB  424GB   422GB   ntfs            Basic data partition  msftdata
12      424GB   498GB   74,3GB  ext4
 5      498GB   499GB   975MB   ntfs                                  escondida, diag
 6      499GB   903GB   404GB   ntfs            Basic data partition  msftdata
 9      903GB   903GB   537MB   fat32                                 msftdata
10      903GB   905GB   2147MB  linux-swap(v1)                        swap
11      905GB   987GB   81,3GB  ext4
 7      987GB   987GB   480MB   ntfs                                  escondida, diag
 8      987GB   1000GB  13,2GB  ntfs            Basic data partition  escondida, diag
```

sudo blkid

```
/dev/sda1: LABEL="WinRE" BLOCK_SIZE="512" UUID="8A74A41874A40951" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="78e04b22-1076-4e36-b8b6-263767dbfe54"
/dev/sda2: LABEL="ESP" UUID="54A5-2C1D" BLOCK_SIZE="512" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="97410e7c-0058-4b0f-81b1-56314a0ca1ad"
/dev/sda3: BLOCK_SIZE="512" UUID="86E0FBEEE0FBE27B" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="da647d65-f724-4004-a61c-ae7bb283c83b"
/dev/sda4: LABEL="Disco Local" BLOCK_SIZE="512" UUID="C2EEAF76EEAF6181" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="7d7e3d7e-c39c-4c44-9200-ed0437f3a167"
/dev/sda5: BLOCK_SIZE="512" UUID="E4442D54442D2B2E" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="d24f4488-520b-4d8b-aa4b-04717d6c79e3"
/dev/sda6: LABEL="Disco Local" BLOCK_SIZE="512" UUID="BE923F5F923F1AFB" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="2dad7eff-ff79-4e30-b3fa-95b008c08224"
/dev/sda7: BLOCK_SIZE="512" UUID="6E30F94130F910B7" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="73c48cb4-7d7c-4bac-9ad4-985bd6161dcb"
/dev/sda8: LABEL="Recovery" BLOCK_SIZE="512" UUID="4A10093510092991" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="db40dc9a-2bcf-4539-9191-6a719677cb58"
/dev/sda9: UUID="BC35-0777" BLOCK_SIZE="512" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="17cd62bb-153e-3e43-ac7a-bd1983096d6d"
/dev/sda10: UUID="ae5267ee-1de8-45da-9fd2-2fdb892772da" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="cc60f411-13fe-4261-9dce-d23c53ff794a"
/dev/sda11: UUID="37ca1ca6-9bfe-4cb3-b086-fb3f0f030b21" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="38dc4743-261b-46f3-b0ad-2437169e86d9"
/dev/sda12: UUID="fb259a29-6ddd-41ff-a1a3-c451bcc391cb" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="0ee33db1-e400-4bf8-85b5-84e5f154bc11"
```

efibootmgr -v

```
BootCurrent: 0004
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0004,0006,0003,2003,2001,2002
Boot0001* Realtek PXE   PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1c,0x3)/Pci(0x0,0x0)/MAC(2c600c9e5af1,0)/IPv4(0.0.0.00.0.0.0,0,0)RC
Boot0002* Realtek PXE   PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1c,0x3)/Pci(0x0,0x0)/MAC(2c600c9e5af1,0)/IPv6([::]:<->[::]:,0,0)RC
Boot0003* Windows Boot Manager  HD(2,GPT,97410e7c-0058-4b0f-81b1-56314a0ca1ad,0x200800,0x32000)/File(\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi)WINDOWS.........x...B.C.D.O.B.J.E.C.T.=.{.9.d.e.a.8.6.2.c.-.5.c.d.d.-.4.e.7.0.-.a.c.c.1.-.f.3.2.b.3.4.4.d.4.7.9.5.}....................
Boot0004* Manjaro   HD(9,GPT,17cd62bb-153e-3e43-ac7a-bd1983096d6d,0x69137800,0x100000)/File(\EFI\Manjaro\grubx64.efi)
Boot0006* ubuntu    HD(2,GPT,97410e7c-0058-4b0f-81b1-56314a0ca1ad,0x200800,0x32000)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi)
Boot2001* EFI USB Device    RC
Boot2002* EFI DVD/CDROM RC
Boot2003* EFI Network   RC
```

Comment: `os-prober` shows Ubuntu, may be you need to run `sudo update-grub`. Since your problem seems to be in Manjaro, you may need to ask  at the [Manjaro forum](https://forum.manjaro.org/), they'll know better.

Comment: sudo update-grub shows ubuntu, but when I restart don't show (??) I also ask at Manjaro forum. I'm looking..

Comment: efibootmgr -v show a similar entry for Windows and Ubuntu ??

Comment: Yes, you can also use you EFI-boot-menu to boot Ubuntu. In Ubuntu you'd run `sudo update-grub`. You can configure UEFI boot-order and put Ubuntu in the first place, then you'll use Ubuntu's boot-loader.

Comment: I changed the boot-order, and put Ubuntu in the first place. When I restart I don't get Ubuntu, but grub minimal (??)

Comment: I don't know what you did, probably you moved your Ubuntu partition around and now Grub doesn't find it's configuration files. Try [Boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) to reinstall Bootloader.